# Potential Use of DENSE_RANK() in SQL

Tags: sql, row-number, dense-rank

In SQL I'm looking for a potential function which I can use to apply a row number each time a certain criteria is met.

Each time the Unique ID is the same (i.e. same person) and the `Dep_Group` is `WES` then give that row the same number if they follow on from one another. What I'm trying to do is eventually squish those rows into one, hopefully by adding in a GROUP BY `New_Col` clause to the end. So in essence `Line` 1 & 2 become one line, also `Line` 5 & 6.

```
|Line| Uniq_ID | Start_DT      | End_DT        | Sequence | Department | Dep_Group | New_Col|
| 1  |   1     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    1     |     WES    |    WES    |     1  |
| 2  |   1     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    2     |     WES    |    WES    |     1  |
| 3  |   1     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    3     |     DEM    |    NULL   |     2  |
| 4  |   2     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    1     |     WES    |    WES    |     3  |
| 5  |   3     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    1     |     WES    |    WES    |     4  |
| 6  |   3     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    2     |     WES    |    WES    |     4  |
| 7  |   4     | 2023-01-02    | 2023-01-03    |    1     |     DEM    |    NULL   |     5  |
```

Example of the code I have so far which is not quite working as I wanted with DENSE_RANK():

```
SELECT Line
       ,Uniq_ID
       ,Start_DT
       ,End_DT
       ,Sequence
       ,Department
       ,Dep_Group
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Uniq_ID, Dep_Group ORDER BY Sequence) AS New_Col

FROM TblA
```

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? YOu tagged [[tagt:MySQL]], but that doesn't work with SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward: use running sum which increments if not (previous group = wes and current group = wes):

```
with cte1 as (
  select *
       , case when lag(dep_group) over (partition by uniq_id order by sequence) = 'WES' and dep_group = 'WES' then 0 else 1 end as incr
  from t
), cte2 as (
  select *
       , sum(incr) over (partition by uniq_id order by sequence) as grp_num
   from cte1
)
select *
from cte2
```

This gives you the following result:

| line | uniq_id | start_dt | end_dt | sequence | department | dep_group | incr | grp_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 1 | WES | WES | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2 | WES | WES | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 3 | DEM | *null* | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 1 | WES | WES | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 1 | WES | WES | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2 | WES | WES | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 1 | DEM | *null* | 1 | 1 |

The `grp_num` column can be used to group rows along with `uniq_id`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I hadn't thought about this method at all so hugely appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Line,
       Uniq_ID,
       Start_DT,
       End_DT,
       Sequence,
       Department,
       Dep_Group,
       SUM(Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Uniq_ID ORDER BY Sequence) AS New_Col
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         IIF(LAG(Dep_Group) OVER (PARTITION BY Uniq_ID ORDER BY Sequence) = 'WES' AND Dep_Group = 'WES', 0, 1) AS Flag
  FROM TblA
) AS subquery;
```

Comment: What does `IIF` do?